# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lp@f7269a6

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, service

I'm getting this exception but I don't know what is the reason for this.

I have searched for this error and I've seen that some people have registered a service, but I don't know which service it is.

This is the result of flutter doctor:

[image]

This is the message that results everytime when I run my app:

[image]

Update: I was looking for answer to my problem and I found that if I add these lines to my android\app\build.gradle everything works and the message doesn't show again.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your situation. Can you use a debugger post stack trace or something?

Comment: yes I already add 1 photo about of what I see when I run the app and other one when I run the command of flutter doctor. thanks for your help

Comment: When does this error appear? When you start the app or if you do a specific activity?

Comment: After a while my application is running, and it does not appear in an specific activity, just while is running, if a change to other view, if a press a button, etc. I think this started to appear when I added push notifications to my app but I have changed configurations and still appears

Comment: I didn't see this error before. But it says that there is a problem with the service LP. I don't know what it is (custom or public). You might look for it and consider replacing it.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help I'll look for it

Comment: I have this issue too. It is happening when I add the AdMob package. It's some issue on firebase package.